# Numerical Matrix CSV -> Covariance Matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, covariance, numerical

I have a CSV file containing a numerical matrix with over two thousand New York Stock Exchange listed companies' value over two years.

It seems like it should be really simple - I want to attain a covariance matrix formed from the CSV matrix.

As far as I'm aware I simply need to:

1. Import the data as numerical matrix (just the data no headings etc) using the MATLAB `Import Data` button.
2. Press `save as` on the workspace variable and make e.g. `NYSE.mat`.
3. In my function call cov(`NYSE.mat`);

This should access the matrix and return a large covariance matrix from my data. The `cov()` function works when i manually input an example matrix of for example:

`[5 0 3 7; 1 -5 7 3; 4 9 8 10];`

But for some reason whenever I try to call cov(`NYSE.mat`); only one number is returned, rather than a covariance matrix.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and I feel the answer should be really simple.

I'm running on MATLAB R2016a.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need to manually save the workspace name in step 2. As part of your import process you once you click the import button the variable should be loaded into workspace with the name of the file (maybe NYSE)

Try `Load('NYSE.mat')` and see what appears in your workspace.

Once you figure out the name of the variable, calling the function with that.

Comment: Please see my comment for further information on the issue. Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file is without any header lines (not sure if any CSV file needs them) and contains only numbers, you can simply call

```matlab
x = importdata('<nameofyourcsv>.csv');
```

and then

`c = cov(x);`

or even do it in one step:

```
c = cov(importdata('nameofcsv.csv'));
```

This function is equivalent of clicking on the button you mention. However, if your file contains header lines, you have to specify its number and call this function with more parameters:

```matlab
x = importdata('nameofcsv.csv',',', nh); % nh is a number of header lines
```

`x` will no longer be a regular MATLAB matrix but a structure with following fields: `data`, `textdata`, and `colheaders`. `cov(x.data)` will calculate covariance. Not sure why you would need to save anything in a mat file, though. If you wish, you would probably need to assign a value from a `data` field to a regular variable and then save such variable. Otherwise, you will save the whole `x` structure.

---

For instance, the following file, test.csv:

```
95.01,76.21,61.54,40.57,5.79,20.28,1.53
23.11,45.65,79.19,93.55,35.29,19.87,74.68
60.68,1.85,92.18,91.69,81.32,60.38,44.51
48.60,82.14,73.82,41.03,0.99,27.22,93.18
89.13,44.47,17.63,89.36,13.89,19.88,46.60
```

can be imported by calling `importdata`:

```
>> x = importdata('test.csv')
x =
   95.0100   76.2100   61.5400   40.5700    5.7900   20.2800    1.5300
   23.1100   45.6500   79.1900   93.5500   35.2900   19.8700   74.6800
   60.6800    1.8500   92.1800   91.6900   81.3200   60.3800   44.5100
   48.6000   82.1400   73.8200   41.0300    0.9900   27.2200   93.1800
   89.1300   44.4700   17.6300   89.3600   13.8900   19.8800   46.6000
```

---

EDIT

I downloaded the file and copy pasted this command from your answer:

```
c = importdata('nyse_data_matrix_no_tags.csv');
```

Then, I opened the file in a text editor and copied 1st and 20th row of numbers in the file and created a matrix in MATLAB:

```
x = [46.09,24.69,156.78,5.95,21.14,76.17,55.51,7.04,38.87,19.58,47.57,7.73,119.44,1.61,44.55,24.9,50.89,4.87,26.25,15.95,15.96,39.14,121.27,15.7,25.91,25.8,69.7,16.32,12.86,7.89,247.4,27.11,41.6,5.14,47.77,40.98,13.78,26.058,14.56,41.05,24.27,47.13,40.92,27,85.04,15.06,5.05,29.14,7.51,67.5,67.79,42.68,124.86,24.28,27.82,18.08,100.67,109.07,12.59,50.34,18.64,4.75,6.06,16.63,109.86,14.1,54.48,13.9,59.98,16.24,45.53,4.06,67.99,18.22,4.2,117.23,158.75,5.7,2.46,76.39,77.79,6.17,16.95,5.27,12.74,14.7,19.14,14.4,42.77,26.4,14.17,76.57,12.4,42.07,77.47,41.27,60.53,16.97,65.71,56.13,258.4,28.96,760.07,60.46,34.77,133.1,14.19,29.41,11.78,154.55,44.75,15.18,17.52,24.86,36.18,14.1,30.1,47.65,22.92,47.37,61.84,226.52,10.2,65.14,7.88,16.34,170.23,9.6,34.42,15.0999,20.34,58.7,16.6,14.72,14.32,20.89,14.32,13.2,6.05,422.96,21.43,47.55,13.28,27.98,8.16,45.15,15.1665,41.65,17.45,25.73,63.03,16.07,17.56,11.54,6.54,33.18,15.01,357.96,74.88,15.24,27.24,69.08,36.29,76.55,65.72,50.93,72.73,16.13,23.81,52.14,16.05,12.19,71.77,14.97,11.82,33.04,7.86,15.26,72.46,15.42,24.49,15.75,63.78,32.43,36.57,16.24,7.08,26.08,15.74,14.78,16.22,16.85,23.32,31.14,12.72,6.7,26.65,24,12.95,129.92,20.07,11.28,34.66,12.86,17.5,26.5,0.7038,1.22,128.98,23.33,19.2,15.64,8.34,45.01,38.14,50.31,13.11,17.4,47.15,79.29,8.24,28.92,24.97,1.92,77.16,126.5,8.97,3.97,12.85,30.75,37.82,2.36,10.37,52.28,1.56,53,47.33,41.32,10.65,15.24,39.5,94.42,12,54.25,48.03,3.72,6.34,18.5,23.47,26.74,8.74,6.7,7.08,70.92,27.3,65.43,18.776,7.82,16.8,12.0625,124.24,29.79,22.88,29.4,66.44,28.88,1.505,0.8642,10.37,47.14,99.83,133.87,46.41,4.88,57.63,14.45,11.2,34.99,11.06,129.25,7.71,35.2,2.29,2.53,1.65,13.74,15.6,11.84,59.79,33.85,62.48,72.34,25.15,131.2,61.13,2.17,5.1,53.35,26.9,43.15,10.8,63.61,130.91,81.42,45.29,17.58,415.79,118.64,73.88,9.85,79.22,43.39,4.86,32.18,68.36,60.21,34.15,19.47,23.39,29.96,39.58,14.66,5.98,70.87,25.9,38.64,90.45,165.2,46.57,83.18,16.48,134.15,54.68,62.51,12.25,24.33,17.69,60.73,11.51,15.6,85.99,80.81,59.9,17.48,30.73,104.34,0.94,86.03,82.73,14.41,34.05,17.2,11.98,13,52.5,39.2,19.58,101.59,26.38,44.13,18.72,23.3,32.05,27,26.12,13.13,18.58,6.07,73.74,3.53,42.4,12.21,15.72,16.71,26.27,26.69,4.52,35.99,26.1,17.31,45.61,67.9,11.15,13.08,1.1,9.7001,17.51,59.8,26.27,86.95,18.95,26.75,34.33,66.72,107.98,9.7,18.27,24.16,56.8,46.56,91.69,21.43,78.75,3.37,13.71,31.73,100.39,5.65,6.98,85.21,97.84,13.5,26.19,42.43,26.73,10.11,47.95,102.84,66.95,28.35,14.07,5.25,23.68,127.43,11.41,10.43,4.19,25.48,19.78,72.08,53.59,17.41,36.57,92.37,127.48,23.98,16.46,5.28,24.76,9.1,68.33,64.45,8.15,18.54,8.85,119.72,3.62,20.49,2.57,94.05,16.99,25.93,25.12,25.71,9.68,81.26,16.7,77.21,37.45,80.43,6.95,24.95,87.1,20.74,31.82,25.44,25.48,25.5515,46.96,19.11,43.49,10,8.68,16.99,120.79,3.95,1.91,76.54,7.8,33.71,14.59,13.5,15.99,42.6,38.86,46.76,8.1,23.14,23.04,17.39,15.4399,13.62,14,125.94,13.92,22.98,48.68,4.62,68.17,1.14,9.82,29.75,73.66,6.51,92.28,25.53,25.6,25.63,7.59,72.9,25.23,10.41,27.87,10.81,48.76,11.38,3.76,71.78,13.21,53.59,25.55,42.43,68.21,66.25,37.2,6.1,6.24,84.58,13.17,13.2,22.92,82.95,28.9,6.07,74.57,29.35,74.89,64.46,77.91,30.21,11.09,6.34,21.69,56.88,15.25,41.44,1.77,67.42,209.26,11.24,15.8,13.53,15.09,32.8,9.78,12.99,62.77,21.8,39.11,78.68,14.75,10.67,20.6,10.57,36.39,7.24,6.1,13.61,14.58,51.04,20.36,102.48,35.14,12.31,8.98,3.7,81.22,89.67,27.32,13.26,1.54,37.84,11.29,8.98,24.08,4.43,8.54,15.51,36.26,9.33,6.56,43.38,13.04,10.9,54.68,160,164.11,34.25,15.87,14.65,18.72,10.57,13.25,21.08,62.55,6.08,22.72,17.25,14.1,11.91,16.5,17.36,4.93,31.46,75.14,32.84,55.65,21.39,18.76,53.36,52.27,150,11.51,50.35,4.77,16.2,13.83,43.24,94.4,37.89,13.18,35.9,70.65,14.16,11.8273,12.67,22.93,11.11,13.55,9.55,14.24,26.44,13.49,69.92,9.88,157.12,14.93,6.53,13.5,6.83,28.27,13.07,48.33,59,9.67,2.04,28.2,5.82,31.87,65.9,33.14,36.14,30.08,8.49,64.92,4.76,141.98,8.63,10.11,17.27,19.65,30.24,26.53,40.67,26.87,26.25,39.18,1.54,33.93,16.59,7.33,15.36,13.91,1.1,17.12,4.47,15.67,18.68,1.79,15.54,81.13,21.34,27.59,7.46,10.77,503.01,19.74,18.46,15.26,47.57,30.24,6.55,65.34,4.13,13.2,21.55,21.03,29.36,27.27,47.72,10,26.17,7.45,7.62,3.48,18.15,8.2,20.66,97.23,59.46,13.37,7.8,76.6,19.31,9.21,24.18,77.53,0.9,10.8,153.17,23.32,1.18,25.83,42.06,1.48,11.49,24.78,18.24,21.24,6.59,44.54,33.28,64.61,227.17,30,48.14,29.72,45.5,79.45,26.83,4.96,81.03,30.76,72.15,34.48,129.3,65.48,33.48,67.43,34.31,15.05,60.38,32.59,26.84,1.7,32.48,2.31,113.96,1.13,7.3,31.13,12.27,44.48,163.75,4.55,4.93,49.64,7,0.42,4.66,62.44,41.56,21.6,8.18,26.89,33.78,3.79,47.23,27.86,0.5199,45.15,117.21,9.51,74.52,1.8,67.24,22.28,22.735,28.48,13.84,19.61,26.62,25.78,18.95,33.53,21.54,51.22,13.79,34.9,81.22,6.86,15.59,96.42,18.49,31.21,24.57,21.23,22.93,16.32,10.63,11.18,188.35,16.08,18.39,18.17,43.96,62.54,8.82,1.87,33.38,14.9,10.47,16.69,3.2,8.89,3.95,50.02,153.42,7.65,35.53,0.54,18.36,5.24,262.52,4.07,74.98,12.53,13.66,86.82,129.8,24.78,9.8,7.03,21.68,8.1,17.1,7.5,38.4,118.45,6.47,26.92,17.2,7.6,35.32,1.72,25.83,9.11,26.27,13,12.18,12.29,44.75,26.22,7.44,44.5,43.59,24.19,1.35,13.57,65.69,13.29,37.11,6.3,16.42,15.98,25.62,25.8,25.93,101.16,45.95,17.1,35.85,108.8,11.53,13.84,14.7,29.07,68.14,19.1,63.34,13.98,44.89,8.42,11.42,6.6,52.51,7.77,10.61,14.67,11.98,0.4476,15.65,14.54,21.3,122.3,22.92,13.03,7.38,5.41,22.4,117,14.97,17.58,9.98,22.08,10.13,23.79,64.75,9.23,16.0197,8.25,16.56,10.61,15.97,11.8,14.82,39.57,77.69,50.96,41.52,30.2,14.56,15.27,13.66,19.89,0.3292,2.93,26.22,72.39,12.44,33.06,26.14,26.96,5.15,29.29,5.31,8.85,29.28,15.21,21,13.64,130.69,15.04,26.49,18.08,8.27,24.92,51.81,15.55,12.13,24.95,26.79,45.76,82.08,29.35,5.82,36.58,27.79,62.53,26.16,5.64,16.33,13.71,37.44,11.68,90.18,90.17,14.71,14.2,18.3425,20.81,91.59,10.86,21.05,49.61,40.1,77.37,33.53,69.02,8.1,4.47,24.11,8.38,8.9401,39.17,24.28,40.52,117.73,1.99,50.87,47.66,9.32,11.02,6.59,21.86,13.2401,131.19,23.07,140.8,14.33,147.9,74.43,33.26,240.67,44.33,74.18,39.42,9.31,78.67,8.66,12.41,10.29,38.6,18.01,11.96,11.94,49.05,4.85,17.69,44.19,53.67,47.27,37.6,9.86,14.96,79.92,4.09,24.39,26.39,33.6,97.02,98.48,78.25,79.19,31.84,13.91,7.42,8.95,26.08,16.16,6.51,122.79,17.785,186.88,7.77,101.07,8.48,20.3,53.09,70.02,24.55,51.81,4.93,85.78,23.6,32.98,17.93,29.19,12.71,8.9,43.78,7.35,14.59,12.75,3.05,15.88,7.48,15.32,5.4967,24.88,41.18,5.37,25.09,26.12,22.12,18.47,8.23,17.21,14.3799,197.03,15.16,19.27,4.71,73.13,10.714,4.618,15.6,83.55,99.95,944.3,31.95,186.34,22,66.36,20.31,26.93,168.13,72.451,57.37,6.05,15.05,8.8074,15.5,11.38,60.84,17.25,12.82,65.95,10.1,51.415,109.8275,26.9,19.825,15.4293,36.63,16.29,14.34,15.065,8.44,14.4,16.77,14.84,56.78,13.945,25.58,51.74,10.52,9.3,13.52,68.56,25.73,10.75,73.77,11.61,5.34,116.61,116.86,381.835,6.41,37.74,1.75,1.79,140.44,9.2,25.3,4.81,5.585,58.08,22.97,15.12,16,14.62,16.65,15.09,15.83,30.81,14.73,2.89,8.24,10.74,55.84,11.03,16.31,30.76,16.54,4.64,6.11,5.3,14.99,9.62,14.83,123.98,35.9,29.06,410.2,16.19,56.83,12.49,41.27,72.28,18.24,23.03,21.98,71.37,25.02,13.86,18.36,10.773,13.66,37.26,4.16,54.94,14.14,16.5,3.22,20.7,10.8,1.1,12.84,1.42,14.92,4.03,15.25,13.8336,1.93,14.55,36.2,47.92,10.22,2.8,218.58,5.68,75.56,72.75,2.44,14.85,15.12,92.25,15.14,50.15,16.29,14.64,4.39,16.36,15.1,15.25,5.36,13.9,16.59,14.05,14.05,9.32,13.9,52.42,85.6,25.92,6.15,12.62,75.39,24.26,25.27,13.7,18.84,21.41,5.65,44.37,15.54,50.55,14.99,16.52,41.85,10.55,18.78,56.87,1738.1,80.51,60.58,48.96,59.1,1.49,19.69,16.42,14.9,14.375,15.15,14.76,15.4,12.04,63.98,90.63,46.89,10.77,13.28,50.63,1.76,33.79,16.16,27.71,8.73,31.48,62.99,33.13,19.92,7.89,33.58,35.78,46.53,38.53,23.63,23.77,84.4,19.83,28.76,38.37,7.02,3.73,9.61,15.47,43.98,10.45,19.1,5.11,46.7,23.07,61.76,75.6,3.99,11.95,27.51,99.32,37.51,10.17,13.98,26.18,4.71,20.98,53.83,31.34,25.83,53.61,18.87,6.89,7.39,7.81,62.98,18.95,10.9,9.62,15.03,16.79,27.26,20.91,5.66,16.08,27.44,26.23,44.62,22.25,20.49,103.66,2.53,4.44,43.92,15.08,35.31,43.14,10.1,9.07,11.97,20.15,20.48,83.17,1.94,20.18,32.86,18,115.36,11.46,26.27,14.23,44.33,9.84,19.58,10.13,16.95,84.53,4.44,5.49,40.79,26.17,2.54,16.71,69.64,54.29,23.04,46.29,17.98,49.87,45.06,101.78,27.09,16.72,13.53,7.91,13.27,16.12,12.66,7.08,88.33,13.53,14.1,34.57,60.16,77.17,36.77,60.23,37.78,42.56,17.22,110.43,39.25,1.91,5.22,58.17,4.8,26.87,3.34,52.44,26.2,57.87,16.53,75.15,245.43,103.59,27.06,3.17,11.88,81.13,72.92,14.26,37.51,37.51,8.91,97.21,0.9614,24.1,113.44,164.2,11.21,12.02,6.24,8.67,66.54,19.82,42.46,0.4498,54.44,67.66,7.57,51.06,3.26,24.43,34.63,58.16,6.49,39.18,76.24,9.84,19.3,11.55,45.79,180.42,79.59,3.6,16.22,31.99,59.67,9.7,13.17,5.41,98.19,20.12,59.5,12.99,7.91,28.41,40.99,51.01,78.23,11.47,28.75,26.63,54.23,96.18,7.23,67.31,21.02,16.98,60.5,19.01,7.54,20.58,19.72,115.86,65.41,118.74,28.8,174.25,51.32,18.66,13.09,46.21,76.22,18.38,49.8,13.18,7.3,3.96,136.61,12.21,14.39,21.83,62.39,15.55,26.25,29.47,3.81,14.03,17.05,160.73,4.59,80.74,16.5811,1.2,29.52,35.43,8.3,10.85,16.2,11.87,13.3,71.67,27.33,60.52,9.84,16.14,12.8,1.8,2.42,33.76,47.19,12.62,36.74,13.25,16.07,28.24,15.96,9.15,4.05,8.62,0.5429,34.32,49.07,11.84,293.03,2.22,89.6,25.47,58.42,30.13,143.23,19.4,7.14,36.5,20.46,37.11,30.65,79.96,34.92,101.48,21.29,33.24,68.79,4.22,11.36,38.63,9.02,160.35,28.77,19.05,34.19,72.25,10.46,31.28,96.12,40.86,50.86,1.35,48.37,36.98,20.18,117.48,13.74,201.65,34.85,19.46,46.23,23.88,11.91,110,9.77,16.48,12.72,39.84,5.41,29.03,17.25,103.26,15.36,36.63,38.09,71.67,42.97,78.07,16.86,16.47,6.05,26.51,16.91,25.04,60.29,1.26,154.1,27.67,69.33,29.82,27.84,4.73,10.71,26.4,114.37,34.76,14.74,74.67,10.56,6.56,2.28,88.4,29.03,71.35,31.41,115.33,81.56,9.2,49,15.67,40.09,7.22,5.51,14.13,103.38,19.91,13.95,11.92,70.67,59.99,5.29,44.99,24.99,28.64,25.61,17.31,266.23,26.72,25.77,28.55,5.55,100.29,27.69,10.17,10.83,62.27,55.45,19.42,46.89,20.23,21.13,172.71,16.91,12.11,39.7,13.35,6.37,67.69,29.95,85.31,67.72,16.7,20.74,97.86,9.72,62.52,77.31,9.67,9.29,8.64,34.09,10.59,57.33,39.4,104.5,44.5,60.64,154.15,54.89,105.49,3.66,6.18,29.43,5.93,48.71,22,12.28,169.55,60.98,19.52,39.54,24.25,42.45,18.07,18.85,43.41,2.95,6.6,114.22,28.92,48.51,5.29,7.47,26.23,61.28,78.75,9.14,53.37,10.18,89.37,7.71,6.44,35.18,18.74,32.1,58.58,25.94,25.57,25.65,7.21,8.59,75.01,19.97,39.37,20.79,20.84,43.69,30.96,160.22,38.66,46.7,8.36,9.07,23.13,14.75,7.49,33.71,28.42,26.87,38.33,43.94,19.64,138,56.34,8.25,46.6,2.01,10.5,46.07,117.09,140.68,35.69,89.39,16.82,104.97,74.11,5.09,42.54,28.31,37.91,21.2,3.26,41.98,102.32,19.23,55.7,25.7,25.93,81.26,61.1,108.46,108.45,85.57,18.9,74.53,14,25.85,9.88,35.01,63.16,4.78,15.06,14.49,22.2,2.11,12.35,13.79,53.81,44.61,14.18,9.42,116.83,137,14.42,64,97.18,3.42,13.6,14.05,48.17,25.48,13.49,30.72,11.2,15.78,68.42,51.63,32.15,4.22,51.95,27.55,40.18,77.04,4.18,36.79,140.05,108.68,38.41,59.96,105.5,72.79,25.02,20.17,13.44,62.32,50.91,95.22,26.076,49.14,6.76,3.02,68.92,21.8,42.62,57.25,179.69,11.49,12.14,11.1,13.73,17.08,45.06,13.35,62.62,23.28,9.73,52.25,27.11,71.09,14.52,21.59,30.65,40.03,67.61,11.41,15.19,10.64,34.29,56.11,56.44,30.77,39.05,52.14,136.16,14.58,77.42,2.14,813.78,33.86,59.02,14.77,19.64,17.91,20.05,30.37,68.38,17.44,1.21,120.33,42.7,5.03,33.58,90.67,25.13,29.96,7.31,53.42,10.12,46.3,540.23,4.38,21.64,83.73,5.45,119.4,26.99,12.77,14.28,29.64,11.94,48.14,5.03,5.87,6.16,12.26,8.63,5.89,39.26,2.1,1.36,1.26,2.5,0.62,4.12,2.93,2.18,2.12,5.25,19.03,0.3024,34.93,2.77,16.49,16.56,16.87,12.31,1.72,124.2,0.8722,3.26,0.4964,13.2,20.21,3.47,60.5,20.56,30.64,36.55,11.96,10.97,9.59,48.12,12.96,12.91,16.4,16.5,3,2.515,15.38,15.29,0.58,0.2101,9.79,0.135,13.0101,13.5,13.93,13.47,13.81,13.83,13.78,14.42,14.66,7.91,0.6724,0.3199,2.78,5.77,0.8812,0.71,25.94,1.56,11.79,12.23,6.51,0.9442,4.15,0.4398,2.62,3.67,1.76,0.6489,3.1,30.31,3.48,1.73,8.7,2.19,0.1244,0.1183,4.7,14.19,31.89,7.79,0.4569,1.94,0.5899,12.98,0.8,0.91,2.5,17.57,4.05,0.2399,14,13.18,2.36,0.289,1.03,10.97,63.6,16.08,11.12,16.46,8.52,14.47,5.3801,1.95,3.42,4.39,0.36,4.57,2.75,0.5131,6.37,0.134,16.28,15.34,9.93,15.37,14.36,11.3,33.75,15.68,7.03,0.4907,93.1,0.2569,2.17,15.75,2.84,0.8011,0.788,31.33,0.2799,9.13,8.6001,20.5,44.44,0.7498,2828.02,0.475,1.59,11.705,1.81,0.4725,0.5109,0.82,18.2368,0.331,66.17,0.9543,0.82,0.7501,0.611,1.01,1.3,5.05,0.87,8.01,12.5901,13.04,10.45; 42.73,24.76,150,5.77,20.71,74.78,55.37,7.12,38,18.12,47.27,7.73,116.36,1.53,42.68,24.53,48.12,4.92,26.23,13.99,13.93,36.84,108.6,15.1,26.12,25.67,69.24,15.64,10.78,6.72,216.02,25.4,33.36,5.02,47.32,37.32,12.5,25.62,14.16,38.27,23.77,43.8,42.5,26.17,87.29,15.15,3.46,29.67,8.65,65.57,67.54,40,123.54,24.18,29.23,17.73,95.34,106.56,13,46.95,24.27,4.78,6.91,25.59,105.72,16.08,48.25,13.21,55.8,17.1,42.87,4.1,60.34,17.9,3.95,113.03,157.65,4.66,2.29,74.49,77.63,5.156,15.01,4.73,12.18,13.19,18.94,13.56,38.95,26.5,12.92,76.37,11.9,39.79,74.94,39.73,57.63,15.79,64.34,54.04,252.05,28.39,780.81,55.62,33.36,134.42,14.14,27.79,12.13,143.53,45.63,15.68,17.6099,23.63,33.73,13.27,31.25,47.78,22,46.55,62.6,219.45,9.45,62.11,7.53,15.51,167.15,9.37,35.84,15.15,20.25,57.05,16.73,14.03,15.15,21.68,13.5,12.95,5.77,361.44,20,45.47,13.1493,26.72,7.98,43.36,15.12,39.74,17.21,24.17,60.83,16.14,17.06,10.64,6.51,33.12,15.01,355.6,72.84,14.76,25.95,63.07,36.79,74.35,63.84,50.21,71.28,16.45,22.54,49.04,16.21,11.7,68.62,14.79,11.67,31.86,8.52,15.2,69.08,13.17,24.42,15.695,61.23,26.99,35.29,16.31,7.2,26.24,15.54,14.676,15.41,15.91,22.05,32.12,12.48,4.69,24.92,23.65,12.62,126.5,18.46,9.84,33.75,12.42,16.2,26.35,0.73,1,131.38,22.35,19.1,15.76,7.32,44,33.77,48.56,12.2,17,46.43,77,7.5,28.09,23.02,5,71.7,125.38,8.03,3.7,13.12,28.81,37.62,2.38,11.34,47.1,1.19,54.28,44.8,39.22,10.22,15.06,38.667136,90.46,11.72,55.05,51.05,3.75,6.09,17.3,21.41,26.98,8.02,5.86,6.96,70.73,28.08,59.95,18.42,7.47,14.85,10.75,116.53,27.85,21.76,26.66,61.4,25.71,1.36,0.7901,9.52,48.37,97.37,126.08,47,4.17,55.61,13.77,11.52,34.34,11.3,128.06,7.5,36.89,2.53,2.45,1.92,13.22,15.09,11.57,55.3,32.07,54.38,72.65,25.5,118.7,57.38,1.96,3.02,47.95,26.1,40.55,9.85,59.99,132.88,78.76,42.69,16.91,457.01,114.39,65.76,9.91,77.3,42.09,4.91,32.44,56.43,59.69,35.57,19.17,22.11,28.78506072,38.22,14.41,6.21,69.36,24.4,38.01,89.43,155.41,43.73,76.84,14.55,137.21,53.86,66.5,11.06,22.88,16.63,61.17,11.56,15.03,84.79,86.63,55.48,15.4,29.57,101.26,0.69,81.42,75.89,11.31,30.84,16.28,11.87,13.14,33.72,38.18,19.32,101.5,27.42,36.97,18.89,23.56,32.16,28.46,25.64,12.09,17.48,5.45,72.28,3.18,41.07,12,14.5,16.6,23.78,26.7,4.3,32.7,25.86,16.92,42.77,64.28,11.01,12.18,1.06,9.31,17.79,60.64,26.7,84.15,18.77,26.31,33.03,63.4,109.41,9.44,18.65,23.97,55.3,42.46,83.69,21.05,75.72,3.19,13.49,29.15,98.12,5.61,6.39,82.82,101.71,13.97,28.88,42.06,26.5,13.77,45.51,94.67,62.82,28.92,13.57,5.54,23.2,118.34,11.24,10.36,4.1,24.18,19.05,66.13,51.54,16.37,34.38,95.56,121.46,26.03,16.23,5.81,23.39,9.34,63.81,59.11,7.04,17.84,8.74,120.32,3.48,22.69,2.81,91.33,16.38,26.21,25.87,26.36,9.7,81.08,19.47,75.59,32.71,73.05,6.74,24.96,70.88,18.67,30.92,25.41,25.77,25.54,45.03,18.18,38.88,9.6,6.83,18.73,117.13,2.67,1.63,74.96,7.6,33.59,13.41,12.48,14.62,42.32,40.29,45.55,7.97,21.31,21.03,17.52,15.05,12.98,13.15,122.65,13.51,23.8,43.08,4.73,63.4,1.11,9.25,29.82,71.94,6.25,94.61,25.47,25.5,25.6,8.26,73.64,25.3472,9.25,27.04,10.43,47.6,10.72,3.73,74.8,12.43,52.91,25.95,40.24,65.54,57.95,31.03,6.08,6.01,80.5,12.78,12.84,22.79,78.1,26.27,5.45,71.78,28.39,75.98,69.88,70.64,29.83,9.78,5.24,21.61,57.63,14.74,39.23,2.22,67.5,229.93,10.46,16.22,12.97,14.48,32.22,9.72,12.03,62.07,21.32,35.18,77.07,14.77,10.36,20.38,10.38,34.93,7.27,5.86,13.4,14.27,49.49,19.9,105.59,35.46,12.1,8.76,3.71,76.56,93.4,26.7508,13.35,1.5616,37.34,11.09,8.77,23.13,3.69,8.75,15.99,33.96,8.88,7.2,40.96,12.63,11.03,50.51,151.66,159.37,33.97,14.26,14.12,15.95,10.97,12.71,20.91,60.72,6.19,24.8,19.69,13.76,11.67,15.79,16.34,5.08,31.41,71.77,31.24,59.04,21.3,19.4,51.33,45.98,150.93,11.97,46.99,3.62,15.94,12.44,42.09,92.59,34.16,12.75,33.76,68.09,13.78,11.29,11.59,22.82,11.32,12.13,8.73,14.23,24.79,13.18,67.95,7.87,156.56,14.55,6.32,12.9,6.42,28.01,11.1,44.19,58.5,10.19,2.02,27.25,5.52,30.68,65.85,31.31,36.24,26.55,8.14,63.6,4.5399,145.31,8.23,10.05,16.99,18.57,30.09,26.28,35.4,26.45,26.04,34.48,2,32.72,15.9,6.69,16.28,14.04,1.23,16.22,4.14,15.55,18.02,2,15.0649,81.11,19.31,28.13,7.19,10.3699,486,19.44,17.82,14.61,45.82,29.75,6.4,64.72,4.8,13.02,19.25,18.88,31.18,29.1,44.92,8.97,25.04,7.69,7.13,3.66,17.73,8.91,19.92,97.11,61.24,13.39,7.44,74.37,17.86,8.96,23.74,77.81,0.94,10.21,158.07,23.8101,1.13,25.82,42.07,1.68,11.36,21.6,16.51,20.69,6.53,43.16,31.11,58.84,227.76,31.76,48.71,26.58,40.05,73.47,26.96,3.89,77.69,31.86,72.09,34.24,134.19,64.38,33.98,61.59,32.8,14.86,58.14,30.69,28,1.68,31.8,1.57,103.61,1.45,7.19,30.83,11.66,44.5,153.62,4.15,4.72,48.09,6.87,1.03,4.28,61.99,40.15,21.93,7.15,27.61,33.08,3.2,42.95,28,0.47,45.62,114.19,9.93,74.87000442,1.58,58.65,22.12,22.22,28.77,11.56,19.07,26.41,23.68,17.34,31,19.52,47.73,13.99,40.21,76.11,6.56,15.89,93.16,18.9,30.46,24.89,19.17,23.46,16.61,10.23,8.06,165.81,13.99,18.01,18.9,44.81,60.52,8.49,1.86,27.86,14.41,10.21,18.12,3.83,8.58,3.8,50.25,148.84,6.99,31.25,0.71,18.33,4.1,262.14,4.42,73.91,12.1,13.20970759,82.33,126.16,23.09,9.72,6.89,21.29,8.03,15.6,7.22,38.87,120.44,6.3,25.71,17.36,7.56,33.25,1.57,24.45,8.72,26.49,12.04,11.84,12.28,45.4,26.41,7.56,31.41,42.6,23.86,1.34,13.53,65.92,13.47,38.08,5.74,15.31,15.41,26.02,25.712,25.8,98.08,44.54,18.55,34.85,104.53,10.66,12.91,13.9,29.06,71.17,17.01,57.81,13.55,41.32,7.8,11.16,6.27,49.81,7.64,10.32,13.94,10.81,0.7498,15.52,14.21,20.62,109.04,23.01,11.65,7.36,5.17,21.85,114.23,14.3,16.77,9.77,16.49,10.03,23.69,61.77,9.17,15.36,7.87,15.77,10.07,15.29,11.25,14.1294,45.23,77.31,47.89,39.54,28.44,12.82,14.53,13,17.54,0.3641,2.55,26.31,63.92,11.88,31.72,25.69,26.505,4.6,27.83,5.09,8.76,29.12,14.53,21.01,12.98,130.06,12.4829,22.18,17.03,8.19,23.47,51,12.27,12.14,23.41,26.5,45.83,82.63,25.37,4.86,34.89,26.94,64.14,27.98,5.83,14.68,14.03,35.15,11.42,90.18,90.19,14.23,14.2,17.96,20.06,84.41,9.49,17.12,49.09,39.65,78.86,33.65,67.42,8.02,3.76,18.32,8.16,8.72,37.4,23.33,38.52,114.6,1.95,49.43,43.7,9.16,10.56,6.65,20.49,12.67,125.76,23.95,138.26,11.58,135.78,75.96,31.26,244.94,43.04,69.13,37.05,9,75.4,9.47,11.17,10.59,37.12,18.04,11.86,11.52,48.01,5.05,17.57,41.22,53.75,45.64,37.03,9.42,14.2,81.25,3.82,23.04,25.5,31.21,95.85,101.87,76.99,77.16,31.35,14.14,7.16,9.19,26.91,16.35,6.66,130.12,17.82,167.3,7.4,94.74,8.25,19.75,52.51,68.69,22.35,50.39,4.59,81.34,21.87,34.95,17.28,28.62,12.61,7.18,43.51,7.12,14.2,12.4392,3.04,15.53,7.53,14.95,5.39,23.75,40.57,5.33,21.94,26.2,20.78,18.4,8.35,16.08,14.67,194.42,15.58,18.03,4.52,69.18,9.39,4.635,15.05,83.71,98.34,958,29.91,184.75,19.84,63.95,20.38,25.15,168.32,69.68,53.16,5.85,15.33,9.14,15.6346,10.9,58.4,17.21,11.96,64.58,10.38,46.74,99.94,24.84,24.63,15.7076,35.49,15.5,14.35,14.32,8.48,14.67,16.79,13.64,53.88,12.3,25.89,47.77,8.74,9.03,12.7,71.11,25.61,10.45,73.73,11.24,4.59,113.23,113.21,367.93,6.47,33.67,1.78,1.76,127.6,8.66,24.38,4.51,5.89,57.46,21.28,14.94,16.22,14.53,16.88,15.18,16.01,29.14,14.41,2.56,7.14,8.3,52.61,11.04,15.56,28.02,14.96,4.48,5.8,5.07,13.27,9.06,14.79,121.15,33.21,29.22,405.47,16.15,54.74,12.36,38.63,73.47,13.33,22.42,19.85,69.31,23.96,13.83,17.87,10.84,13.66,36.3,3.9,57.99,14.29,16.38,2.68,19.74,11.1,0.7972,12.62,1.32,14.84,4.16,14.99,13.65,1.67,14.2,36.65,47.36,10.19,2.39,217.98,5.18,67.47,67.38,2.49,14.9101,14.98,87.78,15.16,48.04,16.4,14.66,4.01,16.26,14.9,15.22,4.52,13.1,15.63,13.92,11.83,8.35,13.37,47.97,88.18,24.73,5.89,11.49,66.05,23.18,24.66,13.64,18.25,21.08,5.83,46.78,15.31,47.44,14.8,16.29,39.8,10.56,18.1769,54.18,1652,74.88,58.43,48.54,57.45,3.29,18.28,16.68,14.73,14.4,15.09,14.6,15.3,12.17,64.14,88.71,45.68,9.54,13.13,49.41,1.99,33.03,14.84,26.89,8.23,30.99,60.32,32.83,18.97,7.94,32.53,31.42,40.29,37.61,21.53,23.34,84.26,19.57,30.51,36.94,6.75,3.93,9.55,13.82,42.61,10.4,19.09,5.1,45.36,22.22,60.82,76.48,3.83,10.09,23.76,100.8,35.59,9.68,13.8299,22.69,5.01,26.18,49.77,28.86,28.22,57.08,18.14,7.35,6.69,7.52,59.24,18.25,10.96,9.71,14.5,17.13,27.61,20.4,4.24,15.48,25.48,26.1,46.36,22.88,18.66,106.1,2.5,2.82,43.08,15.28,33.19,42.45,9.82,8.87,12.2,19.49,19.48,82.41,1.61,20.31,33.56,16.83,112.54,10.97,26.26,12.72,36.72,9.54,18.19,9.94,16.9,85.1,4.36,5.52,40.98,26.65,2.41,15.37,66.33,54.48,22.33,44.32,17.24,47.45,42.5,102.18,26.27,16.62,13.59,7.88,13.21,14.92,12.5,7.83,86.18,13.63,13.8001,33.27,59.22,74.44,36.93,59.94,36.56,41.61,15.84,107.49,38.91,1.86,4.97,60.77,4.7,26.82,3.16,49.16,26.76,51.04,11.7,76.43,264.69,99.79,25.91,3.47,11.67,78.25,68.79,13.99,37.08,37.07,8.25,84.16,0.8522,23.41,113.6,167.03,10.9224,12.15,6.25,9.13,65.31,17.91,40.79,0.4101,50.8,68.44,8.01,51.51,2.98,22.82,31.82,57.82,6.13,38.62,77.02,9.3,17.3,12.02,42.86,184.08,78.69,2.9075,13.89,33.35,52.31,9.13,13.23,5.42,95.63,20.99,65.95,13.55,7.5501,35.04,38.6,51.56,71.93,9.68,28.7,26.5,51.29,86.88,7.5,66.85,22.13,15.83,57.81,17.05,7.46,18.45,19.37,113.51,61.99,114.01,27.66,177.15,50.49,18.28,12.85,42.26,72.17,18.31,48.84,12.4,7.49,4.39,131.91,11.75,13.13,20.8,59.97,10.37,25.38,30.05,3.49,13.34,17.08,155.45,4.6,77.25,16.2999,0.934,29.3,33.23,7.84,10.45,14.55,12,12.59,70.57,27.04,58.35,10,14.88,10.28,2.09,2.53,31,47.8,12.04,33.69,13.39,15.4,25.44,15.51,8.74,3.94,8.82,0.6112,33.74,46.08,12.7,296.18,2.76,104.1,24.25,58.36,26.73,131.51,19.1,6.2,34,20.25,35.46,31.44,74.09,33.9,104.1,18.92,29.05,66.83,4.22,10.1999,37.26,8.34,163.29,25.84,18.34,33.91,66.17,11.16,30.41,79.67,39.24,50.16,1.22,47.28,36.96,19.69,117.73,13.52,204.04,31.79,15.78,47.26,21.29,11.96,105.37,9.1,14.79,11.24,37.97,6.23,29.64,15.22,114.7,15.85,34.11,36.47,71.76,41.35,75.83,16.03,15.7,5.34,24.84,16.77,25.04,60.03,1.32,161.9,26.57,71.37,33.6,26.29,4.48,9.71,26.4199,113.65,34.67,11.86,69.19,10.2832,5.64,2.15,81.34,27.63,66.56,29.42,111.82,80.81,8.96,50.18,14.9101,39.55,7.04,5.41,14.51,99.73,18.54,13.26,9.71,71.51,52.38,5.77,43.79,25.21,27.31,25.3892,16.5384,247,25.9599,25.5,28.13,7.35,93.9,27.53,10.79,10.36,58.72,51.73,19.11,45,18.5,23.04,161.97,15.93,12.89,36.18,14,6.34,75.6,28.41,86.79,64.86,15.994,18.83,93.48,9.51,66.37,74.28,9.84,9.24,8.43,33.47,9.95,56.57,40.87,101.38,44.3,58.55,148.92,53.07,105.69,3.96,5.77,26.71,5.95,49.04,20.45,10.88,162.1,58.01,18.81,35.46,20.01,41.42,17.28,17.29,40.33,2.82,6.3,112.64,26.1,44.12,5.27,8.25,22.99,68.65,75.61,9.07,53.28,10.89,87.69,7.53,5.49,28.77,16.93,31.76,56.22,26.5,25.85,25.7401,6.03,8.52,73.39,17.69,37.86,20.07,20.07,38.7,29.07,148.17,37.66,43.78,7.71,8.06,21.2,15.01,7.65,36.81,27.64,25.07,37.7,41.81,20.87,133.29,56.32,7.4,45.66,1.77,9.84,44.71,111.33,129.74,33.85,83.84,12.96,101.79,60.87,4.87,41.94,27.98,38.29,20.16,3.28,39.63,101.46,18.22,55.85,25.52,26.35,77.89,58.71,106.91,106.8875,82.26,18.76,74.11,14.07,22.74,9.85,32.93,60.84,3.9,14.49,14.35,21.27,1.82,12.3,13.61,54.78,46.51,13.6,9.1,116.12,134.97,14.18,56.62,96.69,3.28,13.6,14.19,47.52,24.93,12.36,27.7,10.77,15.9,66.72,50.39,30.56,4.05,51.47,27.54,37.84,79.17,4.41,34.21,134.96,105.34,35.36,55.08,92.92,69.47039835,24.05,19.76,12.71,60.18,48.91,90.11,26.55,49.2,5.82,2.9,68.28,20.82,40.56,56.32,171.54,11.4,11.94,10.99,11.91,13.69,45.01,10.93,61.78,19.05,9.11,46.67,23.65,66.85,14.14,21.6,30.4,35.89,63.93,10.56,14.96,9.02,29.15,52.18,56.31,29.22,38.54,54.51,133.93,13.7,71.27,2.27,825.61,32.84,56.14,13.07,19.25,17.79,17.89,31.23,69.13,14.81,1.75,115.34,41.85,4.97,33.71,89.67,24.5,27.18,5.98,53.57,9.24,43.24,526.42,3.48,20.92,81.57,5.13,117.44,23.66,12.76,14.3,32.23,12.09,46.25,4.9,5.77,6.24,11.94,8.45,6,38.21,2.05,1.18,1.19,2.17,0.73,3.23,3.05,1.46,2.06,4.68,18.27,0.3199,31.48,2.59,16.44,16.85,16.9,11.91,1.74,122.34,0.82,3.33,0.55,13.02,19.46,2.6,55.43,18.83,28.86,34.75,11.76,10.8,9.5,48.62,12.54,12.8,16.6,16.22,2.9,2.33,16.09,14.56,0.5024,0.24,9.84,0.15,13.19,13.82,14.1466,13.15,13.88,14.07,13.68,14.38,14.85,7.69,0.7663,0.324,1.89,5.35,0.9,0.77,23.7,1.2863,11.39,11.24,6.43,0.97,4.2127,0.3302,2.21,3.5,1.54,0.6,2.65,27.28,2.75,1.78,9.52,2.35,0.11,0.1212,5.68,13.86,31.34,7.6,0.42,1.56,0.6299,12.7,1.05,0.94,2.37,17.12,3.66,0.21,12.61,13.18,1.52,0.3221,0.6634,10.9,63.43,16.37,10.54,16.52,7.5,14.62,5.24,2,3.53,4.53,0.3581,4.75,2.59,0.7299,6.13,0.165,16.42,15.63,9.37,15.04,14.15,10.95,31.46,17.57,6.71,0.525,89.54,0.225,2.27,15.71,2.89,0.84,0.79,30.57,0.2603,8.49,7.26,19.76,44.32,0.6701,2930.11,0.51,2.29,12.6,2.07,0.49,0.5058,1.06,17.75,0.3579,63.51,0.8301,0.75,0.78,0.4875,0.7495,2.52,4.35,0.82,7.66,12.36,12.96,10.735];
```

I compared matrix `x` with the 1st and 20th row of `c` and they are equal:

```
isequal(x,c([1 20],:))
ans =
     1
```

`importdata` seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Please see the comment I'll be posting (answering my own question) for further details on the issue.